# Changing img src with onclick method that targets attribute list values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have PHP generating an unordered list from database values. For each database key, a new list tag is generated. I have the title attribute for each list entry getting different values for each database id field. So each LI class value is the same but each LI title is different.

I then would like it so that when the user clicks on one of those list values, it changes to the corresponding title value in a different tag, such as `<img title="">`.

For example, if php generates `<ul><li title="23"></ul>` and the user clicks on that entry,`<img title="">` changes down the page to 23 as well. I can get JavaScript to output to `console.log` the title values, but cannot figure out how to send the value to the `<img>` tag onclick.

This is my third day coding so I apologize if I'm terribly off-base or as well did a terrible job explaining that.

```
  <ul id="navigatorlist">
          <?php         
          $stmt = $result->prepare("SELECT id FROM images");
          $stmt->execute();
          $array = [];
          $i = 0;
                  foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $row)
          {
              $array[] = $row['id'];
              echo "<li class=\"navigatorListSlides\" title=\"$array[$i]\"><a id=\"slidePath\" name=\"echo $array[$i]\" href=\"#\">"; echo $array[$i] . "</a></li>" ;
              $i++;

          }
          ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: I don't see any `img` tag in your code.

Comment: Is PHP really relevant here?

Comment: The HTML output alone would, indeed, be more helpful for the question - but is it just a matter of sending a value you have in JavaScript to the `title` attribute of an `img` element? You can do that easy in jQuery, something like `$('li').click(function() { $('img').attr('title', $(this).attr('title'); });`, or if the elements are dynamically added after the JS listener is setup - `$(document).on('click', 'li', function() { $('img').attr('title', $(this).attr('title')); });`

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. I was wondering how to grab onto the information in the list item itself and figured it would be within the body of the function. Also, apologies for not outputting the HTML in the question. I'm a bit new to this.

Comment: No worries. Did that help you figure it out then, or are you still having trouble? To add detail to my previous comment: when using jQuery to setup an event listener, the HTML object the listener is attached to will be `this` in the event listener function - when you use `$(this)` it creates a jQuery object for that element, which then lets you call things like `.val()` or `.attr()` or `.prop()` to get information about that object, or `.html()` or `.text()` to view the contents of the selected element. You can do the same stuff without jQuery, just easier (IMO) to do it with.

Comment: Hey there, worked perfectly and thanks so much. $( this ) was a big help.